# IPtables deny all default

Tags: iptables

I'm trying to learn `iptables` and I'm playing around with it.
I've read that it will process rules sequentially, so does that mean if I "DROP" everything as in the example below it'll:

1. "ignore" every single rule/chain after the initial example
   OR
2. Treat and process the whole file

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
... 
Other chains
```

If 1. is correct, do I need to include it at the end of the file in order for it to be a "DENY ALL"?

Answer (score 0):

`-P` sets the default policy for the chain, so it doesn't matter when and how you specify it. It could be the first `iptables` command, it could be the last. If you have thousands of rules though, then it makes sense to run the `-P` commands first since during the time it takes to load all the rules iptables will allow everything.

If you're using the `iptables-restore` command then you absolutely must have it the first 'cause if you have errors in your rules, iptables will bail out and leave your host wide open.